# Adding words to a char *[] in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a program that reads the words of two files (the first a wordlist, and the second an ebook from the Gutenberg project ) into two char *arrays.

I am trying to add all the unique words from the second char *array that don't appear in 
the first char *array into a third char *array then print them.

This program adds the correct words, but is adding them more than once.
The error occurs in findOdds().
Note when I use a non-binary search method this program works correctly, but takes a long time. 
What is the problem with my program? I apologize for my English.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 24
#define MAXLINES 150000

int add2array(FILE *fp, char *lineptr[]);

int findOdds(char *lineptr[], char *lineptr1[], int nlines, int nlines1);
int binsearch1(char *val, char *lineptr[], int nlines);

char *lineptr2[MAXLINES]; /* The unique words not in the word list */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *my_stream, *my_stream1;

    char *lineptr[MAXLINES], *lineptr1[MAXLINES];
    int i, nlines, nlines1, nlines2;

    /* Load the wordlist. */
    my_stream = fopen("words.txt","r"); 
    if(my_stream == NULL) {
        printf("error: Couldn't open file\n");
        return 2;
    } else {
        nlines = add2array(my_stream, lineptr);
        fclose(my_stream);
    } 
    if(nlines==-1) {
        printf("error: Epic Failure to copy words to char *lineptr[]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Load the ebook. */
    my_stream1 = fopen("horsemanship.txt","r");
    if(my_stream1 == NULL) {
        printf("error: Couldn't open file\n");
        return 2;
    } else {
        nlines1 = add2array(my_stream1, lineptr1);
        fclose(my_stream1);
    } 
    if(nlines1==-1) {
        printf("error: Epic Failure to copy words to char *lineptr[]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Find and print the unique words from the ebook not in the wordlist */
    nlines2 = findOdds(lineptr, lineptr1, nlines, nlines1);
    for(i=0; i<nlines2; i++)
        printf("%s\n",lineptr2[i]);
    return 0;
}

/* add2array: read the words from the file into char *lineptr[] */
int add2array(FILE *fp, char *lineptr[])
{
    int nlines=0, c=0, pos=0;
    char temp[MAXCHAR];
    char *p;

    while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(isalpha(c))
            temp[pos++] = tolower(c);
        else if(!isalpha(c)) {
            temp[pos] = '\0';
            pos = 0;
            if(isalpha(temp[0])){
                if((p = malloc(sizeof(temp)))==NULL)
                    return -1;
                strcpy(p, temp);
                lineptr[nlines++] = p;
            }
        }
    }
    return nlines;
}

/* Add the unique words from lineptr1 not in lineptr to lineptr2 */ 
int findOdds(char *lineptr[], char *lineptr1[], int nlines, int nlines1)
{
    char *p;
    char temp[MAXCHAR];
    int i, nlines2=0;

    for(i=0; i<nlines1; i++) {
        if(binsearch1(lineptr1[i], lineptr, nlines)==-1) {
            if(binsearch1(lineptr1[i], lineptr2, nlines2)==-1) {
                if((p = malloc(sizeof(temp)))==NULL)
                    return -1;
                strcpy(p, lineptr1[i]);
                lineptr2[nlines2++] = p;
            }
        }
    }
    return nlines2;
}

int binsearch1(char *val, char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
    int pos;
    int start = 0;
    int end = nlines-1;
    int cond = 0;

    while(start <= end){
        pos=(start + end)/2; 
        if((cond = strcmp(lineptr[pos],val)) == 0)
            return pos;
        else if(cond < 0)
            start = pos+1;
        else
            end = pos-1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Since `MAXLINES` is `150000`, returning `666` from `binsearch1` is not a good indicator of "unable to find". Returning `-1` is a better indicator.

Comment: Your arrays must be sorted if you want to use binary search. Are your word lists sorted?

Comment: *Why didn't I think of that + Blush* The word list was sorted, but I forgot the nature of a binsearch and just added the second text without using a sort method on it.

Comment: Point taken about using a value between O and 150000 as the indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays must be sorted if you want to use binary search, as stated above by n.m.

```
    in main() ...

    shellsort1(lineptr1, nlines1);
    /* Find and print the unique words from the ebook not in the wordlist */
    nlines2 = findOdds(lineptr, lineptr1, nlines, nlines1);
    ...


int shellsort1(char *v[], int n)
{
    int gap, i, j;
    char temp[MAXCHAR];
    char *p;

    for(gap=n/2; gap>0; gap/=2)
        for(i=gap; i<n; i++)
            for(j=i-gap; j>=0 && strcmp(v[j],v[j+gap])>0; j-=gap) {
                if((p = malloc(sizeof(temp)))==NULL)
                    return -1;  
                p = v[j];
                v[j] = v[j+gap];
                v[j+gap] = p;
            }
    return 0;
}
```